# How to make a padding value to take space from margin?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have several elements at the right side of the screen. Each element should have 16dp margin from the right side. Some elements are clickable and those elements need additional 4dp padding. Is it possible somehow to set margin to 16dp for all elements but elements that have padding could reduce the margin value to "margin - padding"?

Comment: you can reduce the margin by 4 dp and set the paddingright as 4 dp with perticular element.

Comment: @JaiminThakkar I know it. I asked it because I don't like manual math in layout files. If I decided to reduce the margin by 4dp, I would have to reduce two resource values.

Comment: I failed to realize that this was for android-os. Which means my answer has little value and therefore I deleted it.

Comment: I fear you might need to do it programaticly. You could check how to build your own views object

Comment: @AxelH, thanks for the idea. Yes, of course it's possible by creating a custom layout which iterates over all its children and if a child has padding and a special custom attribute like "mergePaddingIntoMargin=true", then it should reduce child's margin value by child's padding value. I thought there is a special attribute in android because this case is not rare